# Can't able to select default value from dropdown in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried all the  way, but not able to select default text value from dropdown

tried below method

```
select_responsibility_status = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"select-handle")
select_responsibility_status.click()
select_responsibility_status.select_by_visible_text("All responsibilities");
```

The dropdown is having 5 elements, in my case i have to select "All responsibilities" element only

[image: Dropdown looks like]

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.select_by_visible_text()` is only available for a SELECT HTML element that has been created as a `Select` class, e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'name'))
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
```

In your case, it looks like a dropdown but not a SELECT element dropdown. You can tell that because the dropdown options are LI tags. In this case, you'll need to click the dropdown element exposing the options (as shown in the picture you posted) and then click the desired element.

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"select-handle").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//li[text()='All responsibilities']").click()
```